# Twitter library for App Engine Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth

I am looking for an Python library which is compatible with app engine and provides an interface to the Twitter API.

I found the [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) project - has anyone has used it on app engine?

Comment: just found that python-twitter uses urllib2 for urlfetch which might not be allowed on app engin!

Comment: You can use urllib2 to make HTTP requests on app engine as per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Fetching_URLs_in_Python).

Answer (score 6):

I just switched from python-twitter to [tweepy](http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy). It has better coverage, builtin OAuth and the Streaming API.

Take a look at [this fork](http://github.com/gumptionthomas/tweepy-appengine) to work with App Engine.

**Later edit** (thanks [jmlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81234/jmlane)): The main distribution was fixed to work with App Engine so get it from [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy).

Comment: Use it tweepy in a lot of my AppEngine projects

Comment: Worth mentioning that Tweepy [merged](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/44749382de131e83df9eb0923899e4a3c9dcd5f7) the fixes introduced in this fork upstream. May wish to edit your answer to direct people to use the main distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) on app engine (support was added when [python-twitter issue 64](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=64) was resolved).

Comment: Thanks David Underhill, I am trying to use this library!!

Comment: @David Underhill: It requires import OAuth2 and HTTPLib2. For OAuth2, I downloaded https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/tree/master/oauth2. For HTTPLib2, I dowloaded http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Install and extracted folder python2/httplib2 to project root folder. I got the error http://paste.shehas.net/show/jbXyx2MSJrpjt7LR2Ksc/

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you can use python-twitter (in its current incarnation).  To use it, simply add the twitter.py to your Python-GAE project, then to create an instance of the API:

```
twitter_api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret, access_token_key=access_token_key, access_token_secret=access_token_secret, cache=None)
```

It's important to set cache=None because this disables the internal caching which uses the filesystem by default (which is not allowed in GAE).  Ideally, somebody should fix this to use memcached...but I'm too laaazzyy... ;-)

Update: OK...this is freaking annoying...you also need to extract the following libraries from the google_appengine lib...meaning you will have to explicitly add the source bundles to your project instead of just referencing them:

- oauth2
- httplib2

if you don't add them to your project, it will work locally but not in GAE.

Comment: Can you teach me how to install oauth2 and httplib2? I just download them from github and put them in the root folder of my project and add import oath2 and import httplib2, but GAE still says there is no module httplib2

Comment: @John you will need to explicitly add those folders into your GAE app code (yes, you are essentially creating copies of those code per application...which is--i know--lame)